# Layout coordinates for a video-texture object in SceneKit with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, scenekit, skspritenode

I'm working on creating an `SCNNode` instance that consists of an `SCNPlane` - type geometry, with a video playing on the surface of the node. This is what I have so far:

```
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 5, height: 5)
    node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    GlobalScene.shared.rootNode.addChildNode(node!)

    let urlStr = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "mov")
    videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL! as URL))
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player!)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    let spritescene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 122, height: 431))
    videoNode.size.width=spritescene.size.width
    videoNode.size.height=spritescene.size.height
    spritescene.addChild(videoNode)

    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spritescene
```

The overall functionality so far works great! What I'm trying to figure out is, how to I get the `node`'s ENTIRE surface to be made up of the video ? So far, I've only gotten it to appear in the single corner shown below: [image]

**EDIT**: it looks like the issue is that I'm only setting the first material of the plane node (rather than all of them...) which is why I'm seeing the other 3 "quadrants" as blank.

**EDIT2**: That first conclusion may not be correct - if I set:

```
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.green
```

I get the following result:

[image]

So...why won't that work when applying the contents of a `SpriteKit` scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `SKScene` and a `SKVideoNode` is not necessary. You can directly set the `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance. This will allow for better performance and will avoid having to deal with scaling and positioning the SpriteKit elements.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/glaurent/aad82c4185f3c92f21dc), I was able to solve my issue; which ended up involving both scaling the video node properly, as well as setting the position properly. My working code is below:

```
    GlobalScene.shared.rootNode.addChildNode(node!)

    let urlStr = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "mov")
    videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL! as URL))
    videoSpriteKitNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player!)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd),
        name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
        object: player?.currentItem)


    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1276.0 / 2.0, height: 712.0 / 2.0))
    videoSpriteKitNode?.size.width=spriteKitScene.size.width
    videoSpriteKitNode?.size.height=spriteKitScene.size.height
    node?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1), 0, 1, 0)

    videoSpriteKitNode?.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2.0)

    videoSpriteKitNode?.size = spriteKitScene.size

    videoSpriteKitNode?.play()
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoSpriteKitNode!)

    plane?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene
```